# R liner mixed model question: mixed factorial design, how to set up random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I am new to R and would like to run linear mixed model on reaction time data. I have 2 between-subj factors (Factor 1 and Factor 2) and 2 within subj factors (Face and Valence), so a 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 mixed factorial design.

Each participant responds to 12 neg and 12 pos words. Each word is tested twice, once preceded by an image of face 1 and once preceded by face 2. We measure RTs to words.

In essence, we are interested in whether face affects RTs to neg and pos words.

I would like to account for the random effects "word" and "subject".

Using package lme4, I wrote the following:

`m1 = lmer(RT ~ Factor 1 * Factor 2 * Face * Valence + (1|SUBJ) + (1|Word))`

However, since Face and Valence are repeated factors, do I need to set up the random factor for subj differently? What would `(1|Face:Valence:SUBJ)` do?

Thanks!